# control panel under Windows 7 will not load?

Tags: windows-7, control-panel, mouse-click

So, I am slowly, piece-by-piece, putting my system back together. Right now the only thing that doesn't operate correctly is trying to enter the control panel via Start->Control Panel– when I click it nothing happens. When I put "control panel" in the search box and click on one of the resulting "finds", nothing happens. When I run a SFC /scannow no problems are found. What is wrong and how can I repair it?

Comment: Are the [tools](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806) and [folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180025) still there?

Comment: If you type `control` in the command prompt, what happens?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by putting your system back together?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to what you mean by 'piece' together. If you can't access your control panel, it has been done incorrectly. For instance, can you right click the Control Panel icon and click 'explore'? Do you have any .cpl files in Windows\System (control pane files?)?

It sounds to me like you need to either a) back up all your data and reinstall or b) run a "fix" (available on the CD or ISO) to replace and fix the OS files.

Comment: this is getting weirder and weirder: without changing anything on my system, I was ready to pack it in and just reinstall Windows within in place install. So I clicked on control panel one last time. It worked like a champ. Right now everything is working. Keeping my fingers crossed! :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is getting weirder and weirder: without changing anything on my system, I was ready to pack it in and just reinstall Windows with an in-place install. So I clicked on control panel one last time. It worked like a champ. Right now everything is working. Keeping my fingers crossed! :-)